# Cannot initialize a class instance, after I move it to a class member?

Tags: c++, class, oop, point-cloud-library

This works :

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud2 (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
```

But this is not working :

**Class.h, private variable**

```
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud;
```

**Class.cpp, in constructor**

```
cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
```

Make failed with :

```
 error: no match for call to ‘(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr {aka boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> >}) (pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>*)’
     cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
```

Why is the two not the same? The only difference as seen from .cpp is one is with type on the left (declaring) and one is already declared in .h, but the error seems to complain about argument despite both way I use exactly the same argument.

Comment: I don't think there is enough here to answer the question, but it looks like you aren't initializing `cloud` in the initializer list.  You should edit the question to show the whole constructor.

Comment: `bar(foo)` is not an assignment syntax. Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are initializing it in constructor body not in member initializer list:

```
struct A{

    A(int){} 

    A(){}
};

struct B
{
    A a;

    B(): a(52) //correct syntax
    {
        a(52); //error: no match for call to...
    }
};



int main()
{    
    A a(5); //ok this works
}
```

You have to place
`cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);`

In your `Class` member initializer list:

```
Class(): cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>)
{
//constructor body
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about "initializer list" before! (Coming from C#, Javascript) Thank you!